# Writing QGIS regex for rounding to two places after decimal point?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, regular-expression

In QGIS field-calculator `round()` is not working in QGIS 1.8 so I try to do the following  with a regex:
I'd like to keep the first two places after the decimal point - where do I go wrong?

```
regexp_replace( tostring( "Shape_Area" / 10000 ), '(\d+\.\d{2})\d+', '\1')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kay, could you give a little more context about where you run this code and what the result you get, along with previous research and things you have already tried.

Comment: Matthias, I edited the original post.

Comment: There would be simpler ways to achieve these results using e.g. rounding functions. Or are you trying to learn regex?

Comment: Doesn't the FC have an 'int', 'floor', or 'ceiling' function?  (Rounding is usually implemented via truncation, like `int`, under the hood anyway, as in `int("Shape_Area" * 100 + 1/2)/100`.)

Comment: @underdark, 1.8 doesn't support `round()` as I understood it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works for me

```
toint(value * 100) / 100.0
```

Comment: it is as simple as that - thanks! (i'm still keen to know what the error in the regex caused..)

Answer (score 0):

You might try `'(\d+\.\d\d)\d+', '\1')`

Comment: tried this before - still get the same error..